# Blockfrost API - input to the output

Tags: cryptojs, cryptocurrency, cardano

I'm trying to use this API from the blockfrost: [https://docs.blockfrost.io/#tag/Cardano-Transactions/paths/~1txs~1%7Bhash%7D~1utxos/get](https://docs.blockfrost.io/#tag/Cardano-Transactions/paths/%7E1txs%7E1%7Bhash%7D%7E1utxos/get)

but the problem is that sometimes I have more inputs than outputs and I don't know which one has the reference like per example in the https://cexplorer.io/tx that shows the user that spends the ADA and where it goes to another wallet, or cexplorer has other API for this purpose? :(
Any help, please?

goes: have the transaction input having some variable that can refer to the output to separate each one in a new object to show in a table

Answer (score 0):

The output is the same as you see on cexplorer. The number of inputs does not have to much the number of inputs, it does not work that way. One input does not go to one output.

Think of it like a big pot, all inputs goes to that pot and then all outputs goes from that pot.